# Changing datatype of a column in database

Tags: sql, database, db2

I have to change the datatype of a column from `CHAR` to `INTEGER` in database. I used the following query:

```
ALTER TABLE cert_request
    ALTER column CERT_REQUEST_NBR SET TYPE(INTEGER);
```

however it's showing error in the keyword "column" and giving the error code as -104 on execution. Following is the error log;

```
Error: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, SQLERRMC=ALTER TABLE CERT_REQUEST   ALTER CERT_R;BEGIN-OF-STATEMENT;<create_proc>, DRIVER=3.50.152
SQLState:  42601
ErrorCode: -104
```

I also tried the using the `Modify` keyword, but it isn't identified in my database.

I also tried the following query but again of no use.

```
alter table CERT_REQUEST alter column cert_request_nbr  integer
```

It gives the following error

```
Error: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, SQLERRMC=integer;umn cert_request_nbr;<alter_col_action1>, DRIVER=3.50.152
SQLState:  42601
ErrorCode: -104
```

Please provide me some suggestions.

Comment: before you alter, what was your column type?

Comment: Use Type Conversion **CAST(CERT_REQUEST_NBR AS UNSIGNED)**

Comment: `SELECT CAST(column AS INTEGER) FROM cert_request` Check if you have data that cannot be converted to **INT**

Comment: @Viandry I already have mentioned in post, I have to chnage from "CHAR" to INTEGER

Comment: @pkn1230 You probably have data like `'aaa'` that cannot be converted to INT. Update first them to NULL and then use simple `ALTER TABLE`.

Comment: @lad2025 ALL THE entries are in numeric  form, no character values are present.

Comment: @pkn1230 Numeric form like `2.5`? or all valid integer?

Comment: @lad2025 valid Integer

Comment: `SQLCODE=-104` means there is a syntax error in your statement. It might be a good idea to review the SQL reference for your DB2 version.

Answer (score 0):

Use MySQL Type Conversion or ALTER

```
ALTER TABLE cert_request MODIFY CERT_REQUEST_NBR INTEGER;
```

Or try MySQL Type Conversion

```
CAST(CERT_REQUEST_NBR AS UNSIGNED)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use MODIFY not ALTER in MYSQL

```
ALTER TABLE cert_request
    MODIFY CERT_REQUEST_NBR INTEGER;
```

And in DB2 you can try like this:

```
ALTER TABLE cert_request ADD COLUMN Temporary INTEGER;
UPDATE cert_request SET Temporary=CAST(CERT_REQUEST_NBR AS INTEGER);
ALTER TABLE cert_request DROP COLUMN CERT_REQUEST_NBR;
ALTER TABLE cert_request CHANGE Temporary CERT_REQUEST_NBR INTEGER;
```

Comment: is there any other option instead of creating a new column and then dropping the original one.?

Comment: @pkn1230:- Ideally the Alter column command should work but since it was not working for you. So this striked my mind ;)

Comment: @pkn1230:- Can you check your column and see if there is any value which cannot be converted to INT something like 'a' or anything?

Comment: It contains only numeric  values,

Comment: @pkn1230:- Can you tell what is the result of this query: `select CASE
  WHEN LENGTH(RTRIM(TRANSLATE(CERT_REQUEST_NBR, '*', ' 0123456789'))) = 0 
  THEN 'All digits'
  ELSE 'No' 
END from cert_request`

Comment: the query is showing error, where you have written the name of cloumn , it's giving the suggestion for writhing THEN

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
ALTER TABLE `cert_request` CHANGE `CERT_REQUEST_NBR` `CERT_REQUEST_NBR` INT(10) NOT NULL;
```

Be careful any data that is not a integer will be lost.

Answer (score 0):

It will be helpful if you specify which database you are using . In oracle the solution should be

```
Alter table cert_request modify CERT_REQUEST_NBR number(30)
```

In db2(based on the error you provided, I believe your database is db2) the solution is

```
Alter table cert_request alter column CERT_REQUEST_NBR set datatype decimal(30)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the word 'Data' between 'Set' and 'Type'.

It should be like this:

ALTER TABLE cert_request
    ALTER column CERT_REQUEST_NBR SET DATA TYPE(INTEGER);

Answer (score -1):

May be, It happen due to varchar data present in field values.

Delete that data, and then run your query

Answer (score -1):

It is because your column is having data which are not integer. You will either need to remove those data and try or you can run a query mentioned in above post which will make your data null which are not int.

Comment: @ Jayanti , I have set the value for all the rows of my column as  "1" which is an integer value. But still I am not getting the query executed

Comment: ok..first cast your data to int because currently your 1 will be considered as char..so first convert it to int then give a try